# Ajax & MySQL populate select dropdown boxes (3)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, database

I have a question about dropdown select boxes (3 of them).
I have used Ajax and PHP/MySQL but stopped on a problem. :(

If I (1st) select 'predmet', then another select box offers me to chose 'cjelina' (2nd) for that selected 'predmet'/'plan' and the 3rd one offers me to chose 'jedinica' for that selected 'cjelina' of selected 'predmet'.

If I select 'predmet'/'plan', ok it displays 'naziv' from 'predmet' but it does not me allow to chose 'cjelina' for selected 'predmet' and then 'jedinica' for selected 'cjelina'.

I cannot figure out the problem.

I believe that problem is in SELECT and INNER JOINs.

I would be much thankfull if anyone can solve my problem!

Thank You!

I have all required provided data here:

[Dump from phpMyAdmin - MySQL Database](http://www.fritexdesigns.com/download/ajax/dump.txt)

[index.php](http://www.fritexdesigns.com/download/ajax/index.txt)

**findCity.php**

```
<? $countryId=intval($_GET['country']);
$stateId=intval($_GET['state']);
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('db_ajax');
$query="SELECT * FROM stavka_n_j_c WHERE countryid='$countryId' AND stateid='$stateId'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="city">
<option>Select jedinica</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value><?=$row['id_jed']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

**findState.php**

```
<? $country=intval($_GET['id_plana']);
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('db_ajax');
$query="SELECT *
        FROM planovi
        INNER JOIN stavka_n_j_c ON planovi.id_plana = stavka_n_j_c.id_plana
        INNER JOIN nast_cjelina ON stavka_n_j_c.id_cjel = nast_cjelina.id_cjel
        WHERE stavka_n_j_c.id_plana='$country'
        ";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="state" onchange="getCity(<?=$country?>,this.value)">
<option>Select cjelina</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$row['id_cjel']?>><?=$row['naz_cjel']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: In addition be mindful of the consequences when using php short tags such as `<?`. The use of such tags is based on a setting in the `php.ini` file which may or may not be turned on in different installation environments. If you use the short tags, and the setting is not set, it could cause your code to not execute properly when ported to the new environment.